# Use of common choke with more than 2 wires

Tags: power-electronics, emc, esd, signal-integrity, common-mode-choke

I've been looking around and I couldn't really get a good answer to this question, not even in Henry Ott's book (so far), so here it goes:

What is the best approach when there is the need to place a common mode choke on the PCB for a 3-wire line (VCC, GND, and digital signal)?

1. Place two different chokes: one connected to VCC and GND and another one connected to signal and GND, or;
2. Place a single choke, one with six terminals.

Another point that we need to take into consideration is that 4-terminal chokes are away much usual than 6 or 8 terminals, and I guess that there is a reason for that...

Anyway, thank you already for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: THere's a lot of types but not all in stock https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Laird%20Technologies/Ferrite_EMI_Cable_Cores.pdf

Comment: What are you trying to prevent from happening specifically.

Comment: It is best to estimate the impedances source , cable, destination,  interference expected , matching attempted and CMRR desired over what spectral range.  Desired SNR improvement? Otherwise you may be designing something that does nothing.  Try.

Comment: I am trying to replace that external common mode ferrite core that usually hangs on the cables by a common mode choke on the PCB. I am not trying to improve the SNR or reduce any signal interference. All I want to do is to reduce the common mode current that make my device radiate more than the CISPR11 limit